# Find path from node

Tags: java

I have a question where I need to find a path from node 1 to node N in an undirected graph given weights in `O(A Log^2 A)`.

The total cost of each path must not exceed *`T`* amount of total weight.

For no1, you cannot use this path because its total cost is `more than` 13.
For no2 and no3, you only can use no2 because the `maximum weight(7)` of no2 is smaller than the `maximum weight(8)` of no3. So I am expected to print out `7` as a final answer.

I understand that this problem is quite similar to the [Widest Path Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Widest_path_problem)

But the problem here cannot use `Prims` or `Kruskal` because the route chosen might not include the path that is expected.

The current solution I have would be to use DFS and find all the possible paths and attempt to compare the weights. I have no idea how would I complete within the `O(A Log^2 A)`.

Comment: You're trying to find a path of minimum *maximal* weight among paths of weight at most $T$. Perhaps you can make that clear in the problem statement.

Comment: You can perform binary search on the maximal weight in the path. For each weight $w$, run Dijkstra to calculate the shortest path from 1 to $N$ using only edges of weight at most $w$, and compare the answer to $T$.

Comment: What is your estimate for the running time?

Answer (score 1):

Dijkstra's algorithm allows you to determine the shortest path from 1 to $N$ is time $O(E\log E)$. In particular, by considering only edges of weight at most $w$, you can check whether there exists a path of length at most $T$ in which the maximum weight edge is at most $w$.

You can now use binary search to find the optimal value of $w$. After spending $O(E\log E)$ time to sort the edge weights, the binary search involves $O(\log E)$ invocations of Dijkstra's algorithm, for a total running time of $O(E\log^2 E)$.

Comment: I don't think you need my help to answer this question.